# how to use pageSize or pageToken in python code for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

this is the python code I got from github.  running it, I got 300.  But when I use gcloud to get role number, I got a total of 479 roles.  I was told by the GCP support that pageSize needs to be used.  where can I find documentation of how and pageSize can be used?  so in my code below, where should pageSize go?  or perhaps pageToken needs to be used?

(gcptest):$ gcloud iam roles list |grep name |wc -l
479

(gcptest) : $ python quickstart.py

300

def quickstart():
    # [START iam_quickstart]
    import os

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
import pprint

# Get credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

# Create the Cloud IAM service object
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Call the Cloud IAM Roles API
# If using pylint, disable weak-typing warnings
# pylint: disable=no-member
response = service.roles().list().execute()
roles = response['roles']

print(type(roles))
print(len(roles))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    quickstart()

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write code similar to this:

```
roles = service.roles()
request = roles.list()

while request is not None:
    role_list = request.execute()

    #  process each role here
    for role in role_list:
        print(role)

    # Get next page of results
    request = roles.list_next(request, role_list)
```

Documentation [link](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/iam_v1.roles.html#list_next) for the `list_next` method

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the solution of @JohnHanley, you can also add the queries parameters in parameter of your method. Like this

```
# Page size of 10
response = service.roles().list(pageSize=10).execute()
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/roles/list) the definition of this `list` method